# is it possible to set the value and access in context.xml in tomcat7 like JNDI?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jakarta-mail, jndi

I would like to set some values in context.xml file and access the same from my Servlet like we access in JNDI:

```
mail.smtp.host=smtp.gmail.com
mail.smtp.port=465
```

Can I do this?

Comment: why do you want to put it in context.xml ?

Comment: I just want to try it, and if it works fine. also i want to give the war file where the above values are editable so i prefer this would be helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes its absolutely possible

```
<Environment name="testEnvEntry" value="Got It"
         type="java.lang.String" override="false"/>
```

Then access this like:

```
Object lookedUp = null;
try {
    InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext();
    lookedUp = initialContext.lookup("java:/comp/env/testEnvEntry");
} catch (NamingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It is similar to how you would add `<env-entry>` in your `web.xml`.

You can read the official documentation of `Environment` [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html#context.xml_configuration)

Comment: Did you verify this ? I tried but it shows javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name testEnvEntry is not bound in this Context

Comment: @Jigar Johi did you have entry in web.xml for testEnvEntry?

Comment: yes having entry in contex.xml alone is not enough, the env variable supposed to be registered for the context.

Comment: <description>testEnvEntry</description>
  <resource-ref>
    <description>testEnvEntry</description>
    <res-ref-name>testEnvEntry</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>java.lang.String</res-type>
  </resource-ref>                                                             hope this helps

Comment: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html hope this link helps you

Answer (score 5):

Yes, see above, and you can do even better than that: you can put the whole mail Session into context.xml:

```
  <Resource
      name="mail/xyz"
      type="javax.mail.Session"
      auth="Container"
      mail.pop3.connectiontimeout="60000"
      mail.pop3.host="pop.hhhh.net"
      mail.pop3.port="110"
      mail.pop3.timeout="60000"
      mail.smtp.auth="true"
      mail.smtp.connectiontimeout="60000"
      mail.smtp.host="smtpout.hhhh.net"
      mail.smtp.port="3535"
      mail.smtp.sendpartial="true"
      mail.smtp.timeout="60000"
      mail.store.maildir.autocreatedir="true"
      mail.store.protocol="pop3"
      mail.transport.protocol="smtp"
      mail.from="abc@xyz.com"
      mail.user="xyz"
      mail.host="xyz.com"
      mail.debug="false"
      password="xyz"
      />
```

Then just look that up as `java:comp/env/mail/xyz` and it is a javax.mail.Session.

Note that if you provide the `password` attribute, Tomcat will install an Authenticator for you as well.

Comment: Awesome explanation and answer